# Specifiying Cipher Suites in Tomcat6 not working

Tags: tomcat6

I'm trying to specify which cipher suites should be used in my Tomcat configuration like so:

```
<Connector
    port="9443"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
    enableLookups="false"
    SSLEnabled="true"
    scheme="https"
    secure="true"
    clientAuth="want"
    keystoreFile="{omitted}"
    SSLImplementation="edu.internet2.middleware.security.tomcat6.DelegateToApplicationJSSEImplementation"
    sslEnabledProtocols = "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
    ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
             TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
             TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
             TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
             TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
             TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
             TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,
             TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,
             TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,
             TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,
             TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384,
             TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384,
             TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA,
             TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA,
             TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,
             TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,
             TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,
             TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA256,
             TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA,
             TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA"
/>
```

However, when checking the server with Qualy SSL Labs, I get capped at grade F for providing support for unsafe ciphers like

> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x33)
>
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x67)
>
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x16)
>
> etc.

These suites don't appear in the connector's `ciphers` attribute and I have no clue where they are taken from. Any hints on why the ciphers list from the connector element seems to be ignored?

Tomcat version is 6.0.24.

**Update**: Even more interestingly, Qualys states that a possible cipher suite is

> TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5

while this doesn't appear in [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#ciphersuites) listing the available suites.

Comment: And you don't have a webserver running on the default SSL port (443) that gets scanned instead of Tomcat?

Comment: In the iptables-file, there is this line: `-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9443` (not added by me), I read it as "Redirect any incoming traffic on port 443 to port 9443"? If yes, the above connector should be used, I think?